# With Google Drive, how can I have a single document in multiple folders/collections?

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

I tried Google Drive today and promptly noticed that the "organize" feature of Google Docs went from a multi-selectable checkbox (in which you can check multiple collections for a document to be "in"):

[image: Organize in Google Docs]

To what (appears to be) a single select version:

[image: Organize in Google Drive]

Personally I loved the flexible concept of document collections.

Am I missing something?

Is there another view that allows me to have that same document collection support?

I realize that you can't have the same file in two folders, but I really didn't expect to loose organizational power/configuration just by giving it a "try".

Comment: How long has that been like that. Google used to have tags that you can more obviously have >1 tag per folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> as of 2018-08-31

To [add selected items to an additional folder](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en) *via the keyboard*:

1. Select one (or more) item(s) in drive
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>
3. Use <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> in the resulting popup to navigate to the desired folder
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the items to the desired folder

[image]

**Note:** You can use the mouse for most of this, but the initial <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is needed to start things off this way.

Comment: These are good answers, but in my opinion you should avoid this (using multiple labels) IF you sync Google Drive to your local computer, ie. using the client app.  I believe that Google made this functionality hard to find when they launched those client apps since it doesn't map well to the way people use local file systems.

Answer (score 44):

While in "organize" hold down the Control key for Windows or the Command key for Mac to select multiple places for your content to be "in".

Comment: Excellent. This does work for me. Is there an official documentation on this somewhere?

Comment: Here is official documentation: https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375028&p=organize_dialog

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What utterly terrible UI design...

Comment: is this info still current. I can't seem to get it to give me a checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure this is still possible with the "New Google Drive" that has been rolling out slowly.  Anybody else have the new drive and have any luck?  (If I revert to the old drive, I can still use the trick in this answer)

Comment: @MrSlippers just came across that same issue. Asked the google support [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/i_UluijK0WA).  Looks like `SHIFT + Z` bring ups **Add to** dialog. Not in the menus, but listed it is the [shortcut list](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en).

Comment: @MrSlippers - Updated to reflect the new version wrinkles. Thanks mateuscb!

Comment: This appears to no longer work.

Answer (score 4):

> as of 2018-08-31

To [move selected items to a new folder](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en) and then toggle to [adding selected items to an additional folder](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en) *via the keyboard*:

1. Select one (or more) item(s) in drive
2. Press <kbd>z</kbd>
3. Use <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> in the resulting popup to navigate to the desired folder
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to make the "Move Here" button toggle to "Add Here"
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the selected items here

[image]

To [move selected items to a new folder](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en) and then toggle to [adding selected items to an additional folder](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en) *via the mouse*:

1. Select one (or more) item(s) in drive
2. Right Click on the selection and choose "Move To..."
3. Use the mouse in the resulting popup to navigate to the desired folder
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to make the "Move Here" button toggle to "Add Here"
5. Click the "Add Here" button to add the selected items

[image]

Comment: The answer is basically the as the Shift + z shortcut, as both are about the "Add item to folder" feature. Please consider to merge the content of both answers.