# One file, multiple folders, via Google Drive on PC

Tags: google-drive

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26010/with-google-drive-how-can-i-have-a-single-document-in-multiple-folders-collecti) tells how to use the Google Drive web interface to place one file in multiple folders. Is there a way to achieve that effect by manipulating the files in a Google-Drive-synchronized directory on my Windows PC?

When the Google Drive shared folders are numerous, finding the right folders to select them is laborious and time consuming.  Finding the right folders on the PC is fast, because one can search. The web Organize dialog has no search feature (which would help, but would still be slower than searching locally in the synchronized file structure).

Also, certain categories of files (in our environment) are known to want to live in particular folders, so a batch file or python script could be used to automate doing that... but what to put in the batch file?

Comment: Good point, never knew that pasting files only pasted copies - answer withdrawn since it doesn't address the problem

Comment: When first using Google Drive, the little .gdoc & .gsheet files that show up clearly contain a resource-id for the file, and a URL to the file.  And I wondered if copying those files to another spot in the Google Drive would result in the same file being available in two places... initially, it seemed to work... but once Google Drive got done synchronizing, it replaced the content of the new .gdoc file with a different resource-id pointing to a copy of the document that it made in the appropriate spot in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

This would not be the best answer to my question, because it requires more than a batch file operation.

Having been aware of the (cumbersome) Google gdata API, it would probably somehow be possible to achieve this goal, using that API.

I've just discovered the (new) Google gdrive API, and it looks much more logical than the gdata API, not requiring to learn weird "feeds" malarky that pervaded the gdata API.  It is possible to achieve the goal using the gdrive API and Python (or other languages, but I prefer Python).