# Organize Google Drive files in a two dimensional grid?

Tags: google-drive

I have a collection of documents on Google Drive. Each document relates to one attendee at a specific event. Currently I have the files organised hierarchically in a folder, with paths like this:

```
[Eventname]/[Attendee]
```

But conceptually the files are better described by a sparse two dimensional grid, where the event is one axis and the attendee another. More practically, I would like to be able to list files both based on the event and the attendee, like this:

```
[Eventname]/[Attendee]
[Attendee]/[Eventname]
```

Is there any way to mimic this functionality on Google Drive?

Perhaps using some kind of metadata or shortcuts?

The best solution I was able to come up with was using "Add to..." and parallel folder hierarchies, but that gives me rather verbose names since I cannot change the name in just one location:

```
[Eventname]/[Eventname - Attendee]
[Attendee]/[Eventname - Attendee]
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! I'm not sure about this question - from the [help], you can see that application recommendations (or in your case, plugin recommendations) are off-topic here. As for organizing your files with filenames, that's hardly a question about using Google Drive.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Thanks! The plugin is a small part of the question, I can edit it out if needed. The question is not about the best way to organize files, or how to name them - I already know how I want them organized, and state so in the question. What I want to know is *how* I can achive that structure with Goodle Drive.

Comment: Yes, an edit would probably be good. At first look, it seemed off-topic to me, so I voted to close. But other reviewers might very well have different opinions. No strong opinion, though.

Comment: Removed the OT part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive is able to have files in more that one folder at the same time. Just use the "Add to" keyboard shortcut. For details see:

- [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101667/88163) to [What is the mechanics of items in multiple folders](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101665/)
- and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/95180/88163) and [this other](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73734/88163) answers to [With Google Drive, how can I have a single document in multiple folders/collections?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26010/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is an option I have considered, and it might very well be the best, or perhaps only, option. What makes me less enthusiastic about it is the naming issue, as described at the very end of my question. Is there any way to give the file different names in different locations?

Comment: I think that you are confusing file names with file paths. On Google Drive, files can only have one file name, but they could have many file paths, one for each folder hierarchy.

Comment: By the way, on Google Drive , at the server side, files are handled by the system by the file id not by file paths - file names.